# How to hide the VSCode update dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get the VSCode update dialog a bit too often and do not want to click it away anymore. Is there a way to make sure that it is never displayed anymore?

Answer (score -1):

Press ESC.

VS Code is all about high-speed workflow and not having to interact with anything except your code via keyboard. Everything has key chords, e.g. CTRL-P and CTRL-SHIFT-P. So having to stop what I'm doing, go to the mouse, and dismiss this popup, whenever a background task feels like completing (and not even really then, because the popup actually appears some short time later) just so I can get visual confirmation of which file I'm currently coding in, to refocus my work after being distracted by the same popup, is really awkward. They are in a stupid location and don't even fade away after time like well-behaved toasts.

That said, I think that's really two parts; the distraction, and relatively high workflow cost to dismiss.

It helped me a lot to learn that it can be dismissed quickly and easily with the ESC key. The other half the problem I still haven't solved, but hope that helps you.

Comment: No I just do not want to see it ever again.